# neo4j / py2neo : Transaction error - File too large

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I am trying to insert/update a graph db (~ 500K nodes & relationships) using py2neo. Somewhere in this process, the transaction failed & neo4j crashed. As per the log file - the root cause was reported as

"Caused by: java.io.IOException: File too large"

1. Restarting the neo4j server did not work.

   "Failed to start within 120 seconds"

   console.log >>
   2015-01-04 03:29:40.061+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
   Detected incorrectly shut down database, performing recovery..
2. Tried shutting down the server - to perform a clean exit. Got the following error.

   "Caused by: java.io.IOException: File too large"

   ./neo4j-shell -path ../data/graph.db -c quit -v

> ```
> ERROR (-v for expanded information):  Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase,
> ```
>
> /media/shard02/neo4j-2.1.6/bin/../data/graph.db
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting
>   org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase,
>   /media/shard02/neo4j-2.1.6/bin/../data/graph.db   at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:366)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:91)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:181)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.shell.kernel.GraphDatabaseShellServer.instantiateGraphDb(GraphDatabaseShellServer.java:167)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.shell.kernel.GraphDatabaseShellServer.(GraphDatabaseShellServer.java:63)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.tryStartLocalServerAndClient(StartClient.java:239)
>     at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.startLocal(StartClient.java:226)     at
>   org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.start(StartClient.java:158)   at
>   org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.main(StartClient.java:120) Caused by:
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component
>   'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@66c9c89f' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached
>   cause exception.  at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:343)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException:
>   Component
>   'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@1bf0eebd' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached
>   cause exception.  at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:164)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
>     ... 11 more Caused by:
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.UnderlyingStorageException: Unable
>   to write record[1248649] @[42454066]  at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PersistenceRow.writeContents(PersistenceRow.java:198)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PersistenceRow.force(PersistenceRow.java:214)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.LockableWindow.writeOutAndClose(LockableWindow.java:60)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.LockableWindow.writeOutAndCloseIfFree(LockableWindow.java:162)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PersistenceWindowPool.release(PersistenceWindowPool.java:241)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.releaseWindow(CommonAbstractStore.java:557)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.RelationshipStore.updateRecord(RelationshipStore.java:169)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.command.NeoXaCommandExecutor$NeoCommandExecutor.visitRelationshipCommand(NeoXaCommandExecutor.java:99)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.command.Command$RelationshipCommand.accept(Command.java:202)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.command.NeoXaCommandExecutor.execute(NeoXaCommandExecutor.java:55)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.executeModified(NeoStoreTransaction.java:916)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.applyCommit(NeoStoreTransaction.java:683)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.doCommit(NeoStoreTransaction.java:604)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaTransaction.commit(XaTransaction.java:327)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceManager.injectOnePhaseCommit(XaResourceManager.java:460)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog$LogApplier.onePhaseCommitEntry(XaLogicalLog.java:1580)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.command.LogHandler$Filter.onePhaseCommitEntry(LogHandler.java:74)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.EntryCountingLogHandler.onePhaseCommitEntry(EntryCountingLogHandler.java:59)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog$RecoveryConsumer.accept(XaLogicalLog.java:1798)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog$RecoveryConsumer.accept(XaLogicalLog.java:1774)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.RecoveryLogDeserializer$RecoveryCursor.next(RecoveryLogDeserializer.java:72)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.doInternalRecovery(XaLogicalLog.java:722)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.open(XaLogicalLog.java:284)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.open(XaLogicalLog.java:239)
>         at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaContainer.openLogicalLog(XaContainer.java:64)
>         at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:426)
>         at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
>          ... 14 more
>       Caused by: java.io.IOException: File too large
>         at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.pwrite0(Native Method)
>         at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.pwrite(FileDispatcherImpl.java:66)
>         at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:89)
>         at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
>         at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.writeInternal(FileChannelImpl.java:739)
>         at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:724)
>         at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel.write(StoreFileChannel.java:51)
>         at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PersistenceRow.writeContents(PersistenceRow.java:186)
>         ... 40 more

3. Increasing the heapsize (to 2GB on the 8GB CentOS 6.0 box) did not help. Also tried bumping up values in neo4j-wrapper.conf. Server fails to start..

I am pretty much stuck, and would really appreciate if any pointers can be suggested.

Comment: Sounds like a filesystem limit issue, like if this `/media/shard02` was a FAT-32 filesystem (or similar) and you hit the limits (4G for FAT32) much smaller for fat-16.

Comment: can you list the file sizes of the larges files under `/media/shard02/neo4j-2.1.6/data/graph.db` ?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, my file size for my user on server was too small.
Look at the link below and try to do this for your server, the key is in the limits.conf

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/file-size-limit-exceeded-error-under-linux-and-solution/